# How to add 5 rounds in rock paper scissors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in programming .So I don't have much idea to add some features to project. I can play only 1 round in this project.
But I want to play 5 rounds . I tried using for loop but i exactly don't know that where to insert. Also  i don't know what to insert inside for loop. Any help thanks. Please solve front-end part also.

```js
//Challenge 3: Rock, Paper, Scissors

function rpsGame (yourChoice) {
  console.log(yourChoice);
  var humanChoice, botChoice;
  humanChoice = yourChoice.id;

  botChoice = numberToChoice(randToRpsInt());
  console.log('Computer choice:', botChoice);

  results = decideWinner(humanChoice, botChoice);// [0,1] human lost| bot won
  console.log(results)

  message = finalMessage(results); // {message: 'You won!','color: 'green'}
  console.log(message);

  rpsFrontEnd(yourChoice.id, botChoice, message);
  document.getElementById('restart')
}

function randToRpsInt () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}

function numberToChoice (number) {
  return ["rock", "paper", "scissors"][number];
}

function decideWinner (yourChoice, computerChoice) {
  var rpsDatabase = {
    'rock': { 'scissors': 1, 'rock': 0.5, 'paper': 0 },
    'paper': { 'rock': 1, 'paper': 0.5, 'scissors': 0 },
    'scissors': { 'paper': 1, 'scissors': 0.5, 'rock': 0 }
  }
  var yourScore = rpsDatabase[yourChoice][computerChoice];
  var computerScore = rpsDatabase[computerChoice][yourChoice];
  return [yourScore, computerScore];
}

function finalMessage ([yourScore, computerScore]) {
  if (yourScore === 0) {
    return { 'message': 'You lost!', 'color': 'red' };
  } else if (yourScore === 0.5) {
    return { 'message': 'Match tied!', 'color': 'yellow' };
  } else {
    return { 'message': 'You won!', 'color': 'green' };
  }
}

function rpsFrontEnd (humanImageChoice, botImageChoice, finalMessage) {
  var imagesDataBase = {
    'rock': document.getElementById('rock').src,
    'paper': document.getElementById('paper').src,
    'scissors': document.getElementById('scissors').src
  }
  //let's remove all the images
  document.getElementById('rock').remove()
  document.getElementById('paper').remove()
  document.getElementById('scissors').remove()

  var humanDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var botDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var messageDiv = document.createElement('div');

  humanDiv.innerHTML = "<img src= '" + imagesDataBase[humanImageChoice] + "' height=150 width=150 style='box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(37,50,223,1);'>"
  messageDiv.innerHTML = "<h1 style ='color:" + finalMessage['color'] + "; font-size: 60px; padding: 30px; '>" + finalMessage['message'] + "</h1>"
  botDiv.innerHTML = "<img src= '" + imagesDataBase[botImageChoice] + "' height=150 width=150 style='box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(243,38,24,1);'>"

  document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(humanDiv);
  document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(messageDiv);
  document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(botDiv);

}



function playAgain () {
  const initialState = `
      <img id="rock" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/rock-clipart-clipart-harvestable-resources-rock.png"
        height="150" width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
      <img id="paper" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/paper-clipart-nexxuz-Loose-Leaf-Paper.png" height="150"
        width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
      <img id="scissors"
        src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/muestra-femenina-de-la-victoria-de-la-muestra-de-la-mano-o-signo-de-la-paz-o-tijeras-83128345.jpg"
        height="150" width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />`;

  document.getElementById("flex-box-rps-div").innerHTML = initialState;
}
```

```css
.container-1,
.container-2,
.container-3,.container-4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-box-container-1,
.flex-box-container-2,
.flex-box-rps,.flex-box-pick-color {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-box-container-1 div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-box-container-2 img {
  margin: 10px;

  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.flex-box-rps span {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;  
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-box-rps img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(37, 50, 223, 1);
}

/*style flex-box-rps divs*/
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <title>Javascript Projects</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-1">
    <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days</h2>
    <div class="flex-box-container-1">
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-box-container-1">
      <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
    <h2>Challenge 2: Cat Generator</h2>
    <div class="flex-box-container-2">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="cat-generator" onclick="generateCat()">
        Generate Cat
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-box-container-2" id="flex-cat-gen"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-3">
    <h2>Challenge 3: Rock, Paper, Scissors</h2>
    <div class="flex-box-rps">
      <span>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="playAgain()">Play Again</button>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-box-rps" id="flex-box-rps-div">
      <img id="rock" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/rock-clipart-clipart-harvestable-resources-rock.png"
        height="150" width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
      <img id="paper" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/paper-clipart-nexxuz-Loose-Leaf-Paper.png" height="150"
        width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
      <img id="scissors"
        src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/muestra-femenina-de-la-victoria-de-la-muestra-de-la-mano-o-signo-de-la-paz-o-tijeras-83128345.jpg"
        height="150" width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container-4">
    <h2 id="change-my-color">Challenge 4: Change the Color of All Buttons</h2>
    <div class="flex-box-pick-color">
      <form action="">
        <select name="backdrop" id="background" onchange="buttonColorChange(this)">
          <option value="random">Random</option>
          <option value="red">Red</option>
          <option value="green">Green</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
          <option value="reset">Reset</option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <button class="btn btn-primary">Wee!</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Yahoo!</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning">Google!</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Facebook!</button>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome!
How do you play one round?
Do you have (global) variables to hold player and computer's scores?
Can you trim the code down to just RPS?  Minimal absolutely necessary CSS, HTML and JavaScript, please.

Comment: Interesting use of Objects of Objects for scoring = nice idea!

Comment: Please share the code with me because I am a beginner in programmming

Comment: What do you mean "share the code with me"?
This is **your** code!
Or, is it??

Comment: No I want you make some changes in my code

Comment: I'll help you see what is eluding you, but I don't work for you!
Perhaps it's a language/cultural difference...
I'll be more than happy to write code for money! :)
And, is the code you've posted written by you?  If not, it's not your code...

Comment: Please I am a real beginner to programming. Please solve my problem and post the modified code in website

Comment: Hi Pushkar, I guess you have taken this code from somewhere like github. In general playing with others’ code is not a bad way of learning but this example, containing as it does several ‘challenges’, is probably a bit complex for a real beginner. Start with something simpler. Good luck.